# String Theory, the IKKT model and LQG

Tags: string-theory, loop-quantum-gravity

In Brian Greene's book The Fabric of the Cosmos (2004) he suggests the possibility that String Theory and Loop Quantum Gravity may be two attempts to construct the same theory from very different starting points. He goes on to express the hope that a background independent formulation of String Theory could reconcile it with the atomized spacetime found in LQG.

Wanting to know if any progress has been made in this area I searched and found this forum post comparing the IKKT matrix model of the type IIb string theory to Loop Quantum Gravity. He says  that both display 'radical background independence'

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/lqg-strings-and-the-ikkt-matrix-model.8391/

Searching further I found that the IKKT model has recently been simulated numerically on a supercomputer with researchers claiming the it dynamically compactifies the extra spatial dimensions making our 3+1 dimensional spacetime emergent and solving the landscape problem of string theory.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.12567

What do you make of this line of research and what are the prospects for the IKKT model and, more ambitiously, the unification of LQG and String Theory?

Comment: This question (v1) seems _opinion-based._